# $f=\phi(v)+\textbf i v$ is analytic, prove that $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

**Statement**:

Complex function $f=u+\textbf i v$ is analytic in domain $D\subset \mathbb C$ and everywhere in $D$ $u=\phi(v)$, where $\phi=\phi(t)\in C^{1}(\mathbb R\to\mathbb R)$ and $\phi$ is *strictly monotone*. Prove that $f$ is constant in $D$.

My question is about sufficiency of strict monotonicity condition. I came up with the solution that does not use it.

**Solution**:

Let's write the Cauchy-Riemann conditions:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 &u_x=v_y\\
 &u_y=-v_x
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Now use chain rule:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 &\phi_tv_x=v_y\\
 &\phi_tv_y=-v_x
\end{aligned}
\right.
\Leftrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 &\phi_tv_x-v_y=0\\
 &v_x+\phi_tv_y=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
 \phi_t & - 1\\
 1 & \phi_t
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_x\\ v_y
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now we can find the determinant:
$$
\det 
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_t & -1\\
1 & \phi_t
\end{bmatrix}=
\phi^2_t+1\ne 0
$$
So we have the homogenous linear system with non-zero determinant, that implies the variables vector to be zero, so $v_x=v_y=0\big|_D$. It implies that $\Im f$ is constant  in $D$ and it is an easy task to prove that it implies $f$ being constant  in $D$.

As I mentioned before, the strict monotonicity is not used anywhere, but it is in the statement. Where am I wrong? Or may it be is a trap from the task writers?

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me. Even continuity of the derivative of $\phi$ is not needed.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you, so do I :) I agree about derivative continuity, it is not used either.